# Android Wear audio

Tags: android, wear-os

I am fairly new to Android, but i have the knowledge of development and Java language. 
I inherited an app that needs to include now android wearable companion. 
I have managed to make simple app to be started, send message back and forth with the phone app.

The issue i am facing right now is how to pass the audio from the wearable microphone back to the app to be processed. I manage to make a timer 4 seconds to create the buffer of the audio, which i found on another question here, but now i am stuck how to pass this data back to the app, and how to tell the app to process this data and nothing else.

I was looking into the MessageApi, but it is too big for that to be sent with. 
I was thinking maybe ChannelApi but i havent been able to find any information how to use it.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ChannelApi is the right solution. You would need to open a channel from your wearable app to your phone app by a code similar to this:

```
Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel(
        mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/mypath").setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult openChannelResult) {
                if (openChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    mChannel = openChannelResult.getChannel();
                    mChannel.getOutputStream(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(

                            new ResultCallback<Channel.GetOutputStreamResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Channel.GetOutputStreamResult getOutputStreamResult) {
                                    if (getOutputStreamResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        mOutputStream = getOutputStreamResult.getOutputStream();
                                    } else {
                                        // handle failure, and close channel
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
```

Then you have an OutputStream to write to on your wearble side. On the phone side, you listen for a channel opening by adding a`ChannelApi.ChannelListener()` listener through `Wearable.ChannelApi.addListener`. That interface has a number of callbacks for you to use; the `onChannelOpened(Channel channel)` method informs you that a channel has opened and passes you a channel object, from which you can get an InputStream

```
channel.getInputStream(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Channel.GetInputStreamResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Channel.GetInputStreamResult getInputStreamResult) {
                if (getInputStreamResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    InputStream is = getInputStreamResult.getInputStream();
                } else {
                    // handle errors
                }
            }
        });
```

There is a number of other methods in that listener that are useful to inform you when the channel is closed, etc (see the JavaDocs). Now your wearable app can write to that channel and the phone app will receive the bytes at the other end of the channel.

*Note.* Since multiple "nodes" may be connected to each other, it is best if you use the [CapabilityApis](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi) to identify the node that is capable of processing your audio file, i.e. your phone. In other words, your app on the phone side regsiters itself as being capable of processing your audio stream and then your wearable app searches among the connected nodes for those that provide that capability, to target for the channel that it is opening.

Comment: Thanks Ali, that is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Ali one more question for you, how to add the Audio from the Microphone to the channel? I have the code that creates the buffer, 

byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,1024);
 recorder.startRecording();
while(status == true) {
minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
}

Is this the right way to read from the Microphone, and how to add this buffer to the channel?

Comment: One way is to have a thread that writes to a temp buffer on your watch from the microphone and another thread that reads that buffer and sends that to the phone using the ChannelApis. If you don't need this process to be near realtime, then you can write the audio sample to a temp file and then send that file to your mobile device.

Comment: can you give me a sample of how this is done? As i said, i am fairly new to Android, I tried creating a file before, but it was crashing the app for some reason.

Comment: I don't have any sample of this to share.

Comment: i dont realy need the process to be real time, i can put into a buffer for 5-7 second, and send the buffer to the channel api, or the file, either or will work for me. 
Or let me ask you this, maybe there is another way of doing this. 
Because i am doing audio recognition in the phone App, so basically i want just to pass the data to the phone from the watch to process it. 

It needs 4-5 seconds for the phone to recognize audio, and return notification, which already works, wheneveer notification on phone, it shows also on watch. So should i maybe implement this somehow else?

Comment: suggest you decide on one approach (say, using Channels APIs) and then see if that gives you what you want or not and then iterate on that.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Is the method you shared for transmitting audio data also the best way to send other sensor data from wearable devices to handheld devices? For example, gyroscope with sample rate of 50hz. How about create a buffer of DataMap and send a list of datamap every time when the buffer is full.

Comment: Sending sensor data is best done using Wearable.MessageApi methods (sendMessage()) since that has the lowest latency and the size of data is not large. In addition, make sure you don't try to get updates from sensors too often on a wear device; that can kill the battery very quickly; sample rate of 50hz is to high and I don't even think the gyro on the wear would honor that frequency.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Thanks a lot for the update. I am working on a research project , which I need to sample the motion sensors as fast as possilbe. I found out if I send sensor data through messagAPI, the data may get lost on the handheld side from times to times, since I recorded data on both sides. Would ChannelAPI provide a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: ChannelApi has a higher latency. If that is not an issue for you, you can try to see if that gives you what you want.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Thanks. I will try that out. For our case, losing data is a more serious problem than having a bit latency.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I have tried used the ChannelAPI to transfer an byte[] (Audio data) from the watch to the handheld side. Everything looks good. But when I use inputstream on the handheld side to read data, the size of read bytes was always 0. Based on your experience ,whats the possible reason for that? Thank you so much!