# Send .mp3 file from phone to android wearable (smartwatch)

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new to androidwear and I am a bit confused with the documentation about transfering assets : http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

I was thinking of transfering music from my phone to my watch, so I thought about downloading the song on the phone and send it via bluetooth to the watch.

But after looking at the doc, I noticed the method :

```
Asset createFromUri (Uri uri)
```

Can I use that method to create my asset without the need of downloading the file on my phone and send it via a dataitem on the watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean instructing the watch to download the media directly, the answer would be no for most cases; some watches have wifi radio but that is only enabled when your watch is not directly connected to your phone; in that state, your watch can download a media from network directly but that wouldn't be a very good experience for the user since it only works when it is disconnected from the phone; at least you need to have an alternate approach to cover the connected case.

In general, it is best to use the [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi) for this task than using DataApi; with ChannelApi, you can [send a file](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Channel.html#sendFile(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.net.Uri,%20long,%20long)) directly from your phone to your watch (or vice versa) or can use lower level apis and open an OutputStream/InputStream and manage the transfer yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I am taking a look at the ChannelApi, it's what I was looking for. Do you know if there is a code sample somewhere?

Comment: Look at my response in this post and see if that helps; if not, ask again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31480148/2765813 (that shows how to use low level apis, if need to use sendFile, I will try to produce a snippet for that)

Comment: Thank you, it managed to make it work. I have another question : once the file is transfered, how can I check where it is on my android wearable (File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3")) ? The goal is to play the file on the wearable by bluetooth

Comment: Did you use low level ChannelApi's streams or sendFile? How are you saving your file on the Wearable?

Comment: I used the sendfile method, I build a uri based on the file path

Comment: If you are using sendFile, then on the receiver side you should be using receiveFile() and that takes a Uri to tell it where to put the file. Isn't that what you're doing?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if there was a way from my phone to check the files on the android wear, in the case I'd like to delete the files I sent. But it works fine. Another question concerning the file I send with the sendFile method, how can I receive it with the same "file name", do I have to use the message api to send the name to my wearable?

Comment: There is no api to allow you check your files on the wearable from your phone, you need to roll out your own. As for your last question, I am not sure I understand your question, please explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I created an app that sends podcasts to my watch. I send the file sendFile(mApiClient, uri), and I receive it using the receiveFile(mApiClient, Uri.fromFile(file), false). Let's say I want to save the file with the same name it had on the phone, how can I manage to do that? At moment I send a message with the message API with the name before calling the method receiveFile()

Comment: One approach is to include the name that you want in the "path", so your path can be, for example "/send-file/FILE_NAME" and on the receiving end, grab the path and extract the name.